# Rajawali get object center of gravity point

Tags: rajawali

Using Rajawali library i loaded object from obj file

```
LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(),
            mTextureManager, R.raw.fridge_obj);
    loadModel(objParser, new IAsyncLoaderCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onModelLoadComplete(ALoader loader) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Model load complete: " + loader);
        final LoaderOBJ obj = (LoaderOBJ) loader;
        mObjectGroup = obj.getParsedObject();
        getCurrentScene().addChild(mObjectGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public void onModelLoadFailed(ALoader loader) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Model load failed: " + loader);
    }
}, R.raw.fridge_obj);
```

now i want get object center of gravity point to set it on world zero point and rotate over that point. I try to get data from `Geometry3D` how ever i `BoundingBox` is null same as `Vertices` field.

How can i get object center of gravity without change object file?

Answer (score 0):

Rajawali currently includes no method for calculating the centroid of an object. If you create a *well formatted and worded* issue on the github page, we can mark it as a feature request and work on adding it as it would be a useful addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your .obj into blender and change the pivot with CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + C. Rajawali will then use the new pivot.